# Run bash script from django application view

Tags: python, html, django, bash, django-cms

I have tried to launch a bash script from my server, the script is called from my django application with a click on a HTML button and user input. The script makes a new django site with additional config such as Gunicorn and Nginx.
When I run the server by `./manage.py runserver 172.16.10.10:8080` and calls the bash script, the script creates a new website with the right gunicorn conf and Nginx. But when I run bash scripts from my "production server" with gunicorn Nginx and the script does not work well. I'll get this error with an **u** in front of the text:

Exception Type: CalledProcessError 
Exception Value: Command ["sudo", "-u", "user",
"/home/user/mksite.sh",**u**"newsite", **u**"newsite.braghnuz"] returned non-zero exit status 1

Here is my views.py configurations:

```
def user_input(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ContactForm()
        else:
            form = ContactForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
            from_email = form.cleaned_data['from_email']
            domain = form.cleaned_data['domain']
            project = form.cleaned_data['project']
            subprocess.check_output(["sudo", "-u", "user", "/home/user/mksite.sh", project, domain])

               return redirect('thanks')
        return render(request, "name.html", {'form': form})

def thanks(request):
        return HttpResponse('Thank you!')
```

I have also added extra timeout value to both Nginx and gunicorn so that hey do not timeout. I have no idea anymore so I turn to you, someone who has expericed before and can help me? As I mentioned with `./manage.py runserver` bash script does its job, but with the production server running with Nginx and Gunicorn bash script does not work.

Comment: Posting the error would be helpful.

Comment: Which wgsi server do you use? (probably uWSGI or gunicorn) It should have its own error log. You should also confirm that the user running the wsgi server has permission to execute the shell script. Another thing that will cause problems is when the shell script takes a long time to execute. The wsgi server could be running into a timeout.

Comment: No one that has an answer? Im standing totally still in my project...
Have a nice easter everyone.

Comment: Based on the error-code: No sudo rights/ script not found? Can you check stderr?